# Auto-Layout and 5 ImageViews

Tags: ios, autolayout

I need to design the following screen:

[image]

but I am having problems with Auto-Layout. Basically, I don't know what to do with the four UIImageView at the bottom. They should have a margin of 18px on all sides and I don't know how to make Auto-Layout to force that margin on four imageViews while keeping the imageViews with the same scaled size

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly straight forward.

Just set the constraints at the edges first.

Top, bottom, left (leading), right (trailing) all to 18 points.

Then make them all have equal width and height.

Alternatively you could use a `UIStackView` if you're only targeting iOS 9. Either way should be just as easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that the imageViews don't have the same width and height, they are rectangular, that's what I don't know how to accomplish, make sense?

Comment: They all have the same width. And they all have the same height. That's all you need to put in. That's what I meant. Not setting the height equal to the width. Set them all to equal widths and equal heights. @estemendoza

Comment: Yes! Thanks, I got confused, thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Sorry, that worked fine on XCode when previewing it with different iphone sizes, but when I tried on the simulator, it seems that is not taking some constrains, its very odd, what could I check? I already did the entire process a few times to see if I missed something but always end up with the same result

Comment: Did you check the box "clips sub views" on each of the image views? Also check the content mode is set to something like "aspect fill". @estemendoza

Comment: thanks! That checkbox wasn't enable, so after enabling it, it started working.